# jqGrid setting zIndex for alertmod

Tags: jqgrid, z-index

I have successfully increased the zIndex for edit,add,del and search options but alertmod is still at z-index 950 making it always behind parent modal.

alertmod is the warning message when click edit or delete without selecting any row. Is there a way to change the zIndex for alertmod?

new code but still not working... did I place it in wrong order

```
$("#list-employees-grid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#list-employees-pager",{alertzIndex:3234},
  {edit:true,add:false,del:true,search:true,},
  {zIndex:1234}, //option for edit
  {zIndex:2234}, // for add
  {zIndex:3234}, // del
  {zIndex:4234, multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true}  // search

  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cases where the "alertmod" can be created. For example if you mean alerts from the `navGrid` you can use `alertzIndex` option which is currently just not documented in the list of `navGrid` [parameters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters). Nevertheless you can use for example the following options used by alert dialogs: `alertcap`, `alerttop`, `alertleft`,`alertwidth`,`alertheight`,`closeOnEscape`, `alertzIndex`. See [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1748) of code for details.

For example you can set default value for `alertzIndex` by

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.nav, {alertzIndex: 1005});
```

**UPDATED**: I posted [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/support-default-values-for-jgrid-createmodal/#p26863) which could solve the problem with the options of alert dialog in the common case.

**UPDATED 2**: The feature request is already implemented in the jqGrid code on github (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/2eaaee270e8b98c539fdcaa3da1a9728100da899)). So in the next version (the next after 4.4.0) one will be able to use

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.jqModal, {zIndex: 1005});
```

to set default `z-Index` for all alert messages shown by jqGrid.

Comment: I edited my post to include the alertzIndex but still not working. Did I put it in the correct order?

Comment: @genpet: I think you have some error how you verify that the parameter work. Just try to start [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/zIndexTest.htm) and click on "Edit" button. You will get "Warning" alert. You can verify with respect of Developer Tools that the dialog div do has `z-index: 3234;` style. So everything work correctly.

Comment: your demo shows z-index: 3234 correctly, but for mine its still 950. Did I get the code correctly just like I posted above?

Comment: @genpet: One error in your code I do see. You have to change `{alertzIndex:3234}, {edit:true,add:false,del:true,search:true,}` to `{alertzIndex:3234,edit:true,add:false,del:true,search:true}` which can be reduced to `{alertzIndex:3234,add:false}` because `edit:true,del:true,search:true` are defaults (please see exactly the [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) of `navGrid`). I updated my demo to use `add:false` option too.

Comment: Thanks. Dont know why still not updating, so I edited the navGrid options in jqGridmin.js and its now working..

Comment: @genpet: The new small changes in the main code of jqGrid will simplify the solution of such problems in the nex version of jqGrid (see **UPDATED 2** part of my answer).

Comment: @Oleg, I have added `alertzIndex`. but still z-index of alert message box is not changing. here is my line of code:`{search: false,pager:false, alertcap: "Warning", alerttext: 'Please select a Product',alertzIndex:1300},`. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: @vissupepala: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/zIndexTest.htm) and verify that compare the `z-index` is correct. Then you can compare your code with my demo to find the difference and so the reason of your problem.

Comment: @Oleg, Sorry I forgot to inform, I am using this grid in a dialog. However the alert dialog is coming behind the grid dialog. So I want to give more z-index to alert dialog. I have checked your demo code. Still I am not able to change z-index.

Comment: @vissupepala: If you post a link to the demo which reproduce the problem I could look at it in the evening. I am currently in business trip at one customer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an `alertzIndex` option that can be used to specify a custom zIndex. For example:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
 ...
 pager : '#gridpager',
 ...
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {alertzIndex: customZIndex, ...});
```

This option is missing from the [jqGrid Navigator documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) and should probably have an entry in the Parameters section. You can see all of the possible options in the source code if you look at [grid.formedit.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.formedit.js) and browse to the `navGrid` function definition at line 1702.

Does that help?